# how to get UISwitch in UITableViewCell with text both sides?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiswitch

How would one get UISwitch in UITableViewCell with text both sides?

Background - I currently have a UITableViewController and when it creates the UITableViewCell I place the UISwitch => accessoryView, and the text (only on left) => textLabel.

So what I want to do is have a UITableViewCell with text on both sides of the UISwitch, to use it for a setting:  METERS <==> FEET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve what you want is to add the `UISwitch` and 2 `UILabel`s to the cell's contentView. But I would recommend using a `UISegmentedControl` for this type of setting instead.

Answer (score 0):

Or you might try [RCSwitch](http://osiris.laya.com/projects/rcswitch/) library's custom wide switch. Have a UILabel on the left of the UITableViewCell saying for eg. "Unit" and the wide version of the RCSwitch on the right toggling between the texts Meters and Feet.